# How to enable the new Facebook Timeline?

Tags: facebook

I heard that developers (those who create Facebook applications) can get a preview of the new Facebook Timelime. How exactly does one enable this beta preview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable Facebook timeline, go here: http://www.facebook.com/about/timeline

Hit: "Get Timeline."

**Warning:** Once you activate your timeline, you will not be able to go back to the original layout. According to [this article](http://www.slashgear.com/beware-facebook-timeline-theres-no-going-back-16202898/), all Facebook users will soon be required to switch over to Timeline view.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/22/how-to-enable-facebook-timeline/) is one set of instructions.  Basically, all you have to do is search for "developer", grant it permission, and create an app (it doesn't have to be a real one).

---

In detail:

> Here’s how to do it:
>
> - Enable developer mode, if you haven’t already. To do this, type “developer” into the Facebook search box, click the first result (it
>   should be an app made by Facebook with a few hundred thousand users),
>   and add the app.
> - Jump into the developer app (if Facebook doesn’t put you there automatically, it should be in your left-hand tool bar)
> - Create a new app. Give any display name and namespace you see fit.
> - Ensure you’re in your new app’s main settings screen. You should see your app’s name near the top of the page
> - Look for the “Open Graph” header, and click the `Get Started using open graph` link. Create a test action for your app, like `read` a
>   `book`.
>
> [image]
>
> - This should drop you into an action type configuration page. Change a few of the default settings (I changed the past tense of
>   “read” to “redd” — again, only you can see this unless you try and
>   submit your application to the public directory), and click through
>   all three pages of settings
> - Wait 2-3 minutes
> - Go back to your Facebook homescreen. An invite to try Timeline should be waiting at the top of the page